# IndexOutOfBoundsException in shuffle grouping

Tags: apache-storm

```
    Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 8, Size: 8
        at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:382)
        at backtype.storm.util$acquire_random_range_id.invoke(util.clj:590)
 at backtype.storm.daemon.executor$mk_shuffle_grouper$fn__3568.invoke(executor.clj:28)
...
        at backtype.storm.task.OutputCollector.emit(OutputCollector.java:186)
```

We get IndexOutOfBoundsException when we connect a bolt with shuffle grouping to its predecessor bolt.

The predecessor bolt throws this.
It says 8 because the successor bolt has 8 instances.

Any ideas?

Comment: Which version of Storm?

Comment: It looks like you have a mismatch between the number of items of the tuple while grouping. Recheck your configuration.

Comment: @Chiron - If it were number of items we should get the exception always as that number is fixed. We get once in a while.

Comment: for fields mismatch it should get an `IllegalArgumentException` with error messages like `expected N number of fields but found T` I believe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be a bug in storm. You need to lock the emit for now.

```
 synchronized(outputCollector) {
     outputCollector.emit();
 }
```

https://github.com/nathanmarz/storm/issues/724

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check if your bolt is receiving input from the spout itself. Could possibly happen when you try to emit an empty value from the spout itself.

Comment: I could only reproduce the same exception by emitting an empty value from my spout. As you said this error is random at your end could you confirm what values your spout has emitted before receiving this exception